# Cannot Use BITOP in Predis PHP

Tags: php, redis, predis

I use command SETBIT in Predis

```
$key = 'ONLINE_APP:1234:2015_03_13:12_11');
$redis->setbit($key,1,1);
$redis->expire($key,1000);

$redis->setbit($key,2,1);
$redis->expire($key,1000);

$key2 = 'ONLINE_APP:1234:2015_03_13:12_12';
$redis->setbit($key,3,1);
$redis->expire($key,1000);
```

and using BITOP to count online users

```
$redis->bitop('OR','ONLINE', $key1.' '.$key2);
$totalOnline = $redis->bitcount('ONLINE');
echo 'Total Online: '.$totalOnline
```

and result:

```
Total Online: 0
```

what's my wrong? correct result must be:

```
Total Online: 3
```

Comment: Thanks @misterion, here is right code `$redis->bitop('OR','ONLINE', $key1, $key2);`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just erred in passing parameters in this library. Its looks like it should be

```
$redis->bitop('OR','ONLINE', $key1, $key2);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.